# Running Capybara tests at a different url when on Travis CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, integration-testing, phantomjs, travis-ci

I have some integration tests written in Capybara which I'm running on Travis. In the tests I hit a hardcoded url (given by Pow and symlinks) with the `visit` method. This of course does not work well on Travis. What I need to do is to somehow distinguish environments. So when the tests run on Travis they are hitting a different url like localhost:5000 for example. I put that in my `.Travis.yml` file that it will start a `rails server` in the background which works fine. The question is how do I make the tests use that url instead?

My config looks something like this:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 1.9.3
before_script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create
  - "bundle exec rails server -p 5000 &"
  - "sleep 5" # Wait for the server to start up"
script: bundle exec rspec
```

I'm using `PhantomJS` through `poltegeist` gem. I'm thinking if I could somehow use the  Travis env var. Anyone got any suggestions on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Travis CI but I don't see any reason you need to hardcode the server name into url.

Instead of

```
visit 'http://localhost:5000/about'
```

You can use

```
visit '/about'
```

Or better

```
visit about_path
```

Less dependency is always better. I suggest your tweaking the tests.

Comment: Thanks Billy. Of course the hardcoded path thing was merely proof of concept. Was not sticking with that :).

Comment: @Tim, it would be great if you could post how you solved this and then accept your own answer (that way the question is marked as answered in Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 1):

Travis CI sets [several environment variables](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables) for you that you can use. I think `TRAVIS=true` may be of interest:

```
Capybara.app_host = if ENV['TRAVIS']
                      'localhost:5000'
                    else
                      'http://www.example.com'
                    end
```

Comment: Thx. I tried that, but we discovered that the problem was actually due to something else.